# Zbarsdk query regarding barcode scanning

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode5

i have imported ZBarSDk in my project and trying to access it  it's  showing any class regarding in my view controller ,but if i am trying to do it in  my logging view  controller ,its not showing any classes

Comment: Means you can't access the property and classes of the Zbar sdk right?

Comment: exactly i am unable to acess the class properties

Comment: I hope you imported the #import "ZBarSDK.h" in login view controller. right?

Comment: ya i have imported it,because to access the methods and properties.Is there any problem

Comment: SO whats the error you are getting while accessing the classes ? can you update the query with your code?

Comment: its showing no completions

Comment: i am not getting your problem exactly.

Comment: Make sure that you have added all the frame work necessary for integrating Zbar SDK. refer this link http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html